# Latency between USB-connected keyboard and Reason - what are the likely culprits?

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard, latency

I am using REASON on a Windows 10 computer with the East-West Symphonic Choir library.  I've connected a simple Casio keyboard via USB.  I am hearing what I expect to hear when I play, but the latency is bad.  I play a key, and enough time lapses that it's impossible to play in sync.  (At tempo of 88 bpm, for example, if I press a key on the beat I hear it at least a 16th note late -- almost an eighth note.)  What should I look into first?

1. Is there a way to play the keyboard and get the EastWest sounds without using Reason?
2. Is memory the problem?  If it matters, I can play back 8 or more complex tracks in Reason with no issues.

Comment: Note that the proposed duplicate addresses only the Casio side of things. If that solution doesn't work, then this could either be reopened or asked as a new question specific to the non-Casio elements.

Comment: The proposed duplicate seems like a likely culprit.  Come to think of it, when I was using it with just the EastWest Opus software (and not using Reason) there was lag too - it just didn't really matter because I wasn't trying to record anything.  I guess "you get what you pay for" is true of my dinky little Casio...  thanks all